# Mantle/Mantle.h file not found.

Tags: ios, xcode6, cocoapods, github-mantle

I have added Mantle framework version 2.0 from cocoapods. The mantle files got added into my project and header search path also shows the reference. However I am getting this error repeatedly. I have removed pods and reinstalled, but in vain.

[image]

Comment: Could you show your podfile?

Comment: If the project uses CocoaPods be aware to always open the .xcworkspace file instead of the .xcodeproj file

Comment: I am using 10 other pod libraries. Only mantle has this issue

Answer (score 2):

Using cocoapod version 0.39.0 fixed it for me

Comment: Same issue happened to me today. Just now I updated to latest version Cocop1.14.3 and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Follow this Steps:

- Remove Mantle Framework reference from Frameworks list shows on left panel
- Now Go to Targets -> Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries & Select Mantle Framework & remove it by clicking on '-' sign
- Make sure Mantle Framework is in your project folder
- Now click on '+' Sign & Add it from your project folder
- Clean Project & build again

Hope it will work for you.

Happy coding.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my issue is when I add it using cocoapods